# how to Maintain synchronization for Blocking Queue with Consumer consuming whole queue

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, blockingqueue

I have 1 thread putting Requests to Queue and Another Cron Job (thread) would run every 15 minutes and has to take all requests from queue and start processing on it and also empty the queue.

How can I manage this synchronization and make sure no requests are lost in system.
I have thought of using Linked Queue for the same.
Other suggestion are welcome.
I am new to Java so asking this naive question.

Comment: [`BlockingQueue.drainTo(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo-java.util.Collection-): *Removes all available elements from this queue and adds them to the given collection*

Answer (score 1):

In `java.util.concurrent` package you have a whole bunch of queues to your disposal, however, I don't believe that there's one particular queue just for the scenario you described above.

I would recommend just pick one of the Blocking queues, and in parallel just run a job that every 15 minutes will drain all items in your queue.